# Send Slack Notifications With Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, slack-api, slack

I followed the official laracast 5.3 tutorial to send a slack notification from Laravel (I'm using laravel 5.4). But upon following all the procedures when I hit the url I get the following error. I haven't touched the Connection.php file at all since making the project.
Here is the [tutorial link](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/11).

Screen shot of error:

[image]

Comment: Have you configured a database for your application? Have you run migrations?

Comment: @dparoli no I haven't configured or run migrations. Can you guide me why do I need to do that? And I can I send notifications to slack without it?

Comment: Notifications is an advancend topic in laravel development, you have to implement and understand the basics before, Authentication in primis

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your application with a database connection and make your migrations.

The error is explicit: you missed a database connection and probably a user table.

Before implementing notifications you have to build a fully functional laravel app with the needed tables (users at minimum), and a working authentication, you can find detailed info in the laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication).